# OpenCV line fitting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencv, statistics, curve-fitting

I'm trying to understand OpenCV [fitLine()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline) algorithm.

This is fragment of code from OpenCV: 
`icvFitLine2D` function - [icvFitLine2D](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/imgproc/src/linefit.cpp#L339)

I see that there is some random function that chooses points for approximation, then computes distances from points to fitted line (with choosen points), then choose other points and tries to minimize distance with choosen `distType`.

Can someone clarify what happens from [this moment](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/imgproc/src/linefit.cpp#L392) without hard mathematics and assuming no great statistic knowledge?. OpenCV code comments and variable names does not help me in understanding this code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

(This is an old question, but the subject piqued my curiosity)

The OpenCV `FitLine` implemements two different mechanisms.

If the parameter `distType` is set to `CV_DIST_L2`, then a [standard unweighted least squares fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) is used.

If one of the other `distTypes` is used (`CV_DIST_L1`, `CV_DIST_L12`, `CV_DIST_FAIR`, `CV_DIST_WELSCH`, `CV_DIST_HUBER`) then the procedure is some sort of [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) fit:

- Repeat at most 20 times:

  - Pick 10 random points, do a least squares fit only for them
  - Repeat at most 30 times:

    - Calculate the weights for all points, using the current found line and the chosen `distType`
    - Do a weighted least squares fit for all points
    - (This is an [Iteratively reweighted least squares fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_re-weighted_least_squares) or [M-Estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator))
- Return the best found linefit

Here is a more detailed description in pseudocode:

```
repeat at most 20 times:

    RANSAC (line 371)
     - pick 10 random points, 
     - set their weights to 1, 
     - set all other weights to 0

    least squares weighted fit (fitLine2D_wods, line 381)
     - fit only the 10 picked points to the line, using least-squares

    repeat at most 30 times: (line 382)
     - stop if the difference between the found solution and the previous found solution is less than DELTA  (line 390 - 406)
       (the angle difference must be less than adelta, and the distance beween the line centers must be less than rdelta)
     - stop if the sum of squared distances between the found line and the points is less than EPSILON (line 407)
       (The unweighted sum of squared distances is used here ==> the standard L2 norm)

        re-calculate the weights for *all* points (line 412)
         - using the given norm (CV_DIST_L1 / CV_DIST_L12 / CV_DIST_FAIR / ...)
         - normalize the weights so their sum is 1
         - special case, to catch errors: if for some reason all weights are zero, set all weight to 1

        least squares weighted fit (fitLine2D_wods, line 437)
         - fit *all* points to the line, using weighted least squares

    if the last found solution is better than the current best solution (line 440)
        save it as the new best
        (The unweighted sum of squared distances is used here ==> the standard L2 norm)

        if the distance between the found line and the points is less than EPSILON
             break

return the best solution
```

The weights are calculated depending on the chosen `distType`, according to [the manual](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline) the formula for that is `weight[Point_i] = 1/ p(distance_between_point_i_and_line)`, where p is:

> distType=CV_DIST_L1   [image]
>
> distType=CV_DIST_L12   [image]
>
> distType=CV_DIST_FAIR   [image]
>
> distType=CV_DIST_WELSCH   [image]
>
> distType=CV_DIST_HUBER   [image]

Unfortunately I do not know which `distType` is best suited for which sort of data, perhaps some else can shed some light on that.

---

Something interesting I noticed: The chosen norm is only used for the iterative reweighting, the best solution among the found ones is always picked according to the L2 norm (The line for which the *unweighted* sum of least squares is minimal). I am not sure this is correct.