# Regression of GPS positions in C++ OpenCV or Eigen

Tags: c++, opencv

I am looking for an example of predicting/regression of GPS position at a given time based on a sparse data set.

Given *N* rows of `[lat,lng,time ticks]`, I want to be able to ask what the `lat`, `lng` is at any given ticks that might not be present in the *N* rows.

Additional, is it possible to also get the derivatives at the same time such the orientation of the moving object can be found?

In OpenCV or Eigen that is.

Comment: What exactly is your coding problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a linear regression problem.

Try using [OpenCV's fitLine()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline). Go through the documentation and you should get a clear idea.

Try looking into **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722569/opencv-line-fitting-algorithm)**

Once you get the output line function, a simple `atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))` should give you the derivative.