# what does opencv fitLine do?

Tags: c++, opencv, least-squares

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722569/opencv-line-fitting-algorithm) answer, `cv::fitLine` with `distType` set to `CV_DIST_L2` is a standard least squares method. However, looking at the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/linefit.cpp#L48) it's seems to use a different formula:

```
origin = (mean(x), mean(y)); // this is as in standard ls

angle = 0.5 * atan2( 2 * cov(x, y), (var(x) - var(y)));
```

can someone explain me the last formula?

**Edit:** this is actually a total least squares. For more information read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca).

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) ?

Comment: Of course, it's also says that the first method uses the simple least squares method.

Comment: how should the formula look instead? Maybe it is transformed with some properties of covariances? atan2 is used to get the angle formed by x and y components.

Comment: The common formula (see for example here: mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) when using the line representation y = a + b * x is b = cov(x, y) / var(x), so in origin-direction representation it's becomes angle = atan2(cov(x, y), var(x)). I can't see how this is a transformation of the first formula but I would be happy to see an explanation in case it is.